# Is there so much of a 'technological quantum leap' in 5G technology?

Tags: network, mobile

AFAIK, it is only the antenna hardware that goes into the smartphone/tablet and also the base-stations, where the technological breakthroughs can realistically be present. Every other component of the network can afford to be the same as 4G/3G. I can see how, if Huwaei starts selling complete smartphones around 5g, there might be concerns around back-doors of all kinds. But apart from that, regarding the network itself, the stuff that have to be redone are relatively minor, it seems, at least in comparison to improving a process node for example. Am I wrong? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something (which happens) "5G" is **essentially** much greater bandwidth, which allows profligate use of video and data - and not much else. All the rest appears to be things which the data bandwidth allows you to do.

Comment: You are missing something: 5G also promises low latency within the actual 5G network, which should make it more interesting for automation tasks. People keep talking about 1 ms of latency. On the other hand, older technologies had a bit higher latency there.

Answer (score 0):

[5G extends into the use of a whole new set of radio bands.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5G_NR_frequency_bands#cite_note-2) That's quite a substantial change, the shorter waves behave very differently and it requires new regulatory approval and new receiver designs.

> It is only the antenna hardware that goes into the smartphone/tablet and also the base-stations, where the technological breakthroughs can realistically be present. Every other component of the network can afford to be the same as 4G/3G.

That's a pretty big "only"? That is where most of the investment and technology of the network is, compared to which the backhaul is just a bunch of wires. This question could do with clarification.